# C# user impersonation while using RunSpace class

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, impersonation, runspace

I'm using the dotnet framework's(4.5) RunSpace and Pipeline classes to invoke powershell from my C# application.

```
            runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runspace.ThreadOptions = PSThreadOptions.UseCurrentThread;
            runspace.Open();

            Log("Create runspace pipeline");
    pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(_scriptText);

            Log("Invoke scripting");
    try
    {
        results = pipeline.Invoke();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
                    //Exception handling code
    }
    Log("Script complete");
            // results processing code
```

I have the thread that is executing this snippet of code impersonated as a particular user. The user details will be provided during runtime and I impersonate as that user and run this code. The impersonation works correctly - I have confirmed this using the Name() method for the Thread owner's identity and also by creating a file in the above code snippet and checking its owner. But, if I do a 'whoami' on the PowerShell script which is getting executed in the RunSpace/Pipeline, the user that is printed is NOT the owner of the thread that invoked the above code but instead the System admin account which owns the application process.

Whatever I do, I cannot get the Powershell to run as the impersonated user. It feels like Runspace just ignores the user impersonation I have done in C#. How do I invoke the Runspace for running powershell as the user I want to impersonate as?

Comment: Is this whole piece of code being run already impersonated? Or are you doing the impersonation inside Powershell? Can you show how you are doing impersonation?

Comment: Unfortunately, .NET Framework version 4.5 is no longer supported. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework) for more information.

Comment: @Charlieface I'm using WindowsIdentity to impersonate. Couple of methods below the snippet of code I posted, there is the impersonation code:
using (var newId = new WindowsIdentity(dupeTokenHandle))
{
    impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate();

and again I would stress that the impersonation itself works correctly. I have tested that multiple times. Only problem is that inside the Powershell script run in the Runspace/Pipeline the user impersonation from the c# thread is not reflected.

Comment: Can you [edit] and show that in your post? It seems you are impersonating only after running the Powershell, but it's not clear.

Comment: As I said, the impersonation is done below this method in the stack, so I can't post it along with this. I have confirmed that the impersonated user owns this thread before and after I create the Runspace.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry posting this as an answer straight away as I cant comment as I dont have level 50 rep yet.
Anyway, pretty sure you can just copy the c# from this module KelvinTegelaar has already made:
https://github.com/KelvinTegelaar/RunAsUser

I use it, and it works great. Its a PowerShell module, but its most c# anyway. In PowerShell you use it like:

invoke-ascurrentuser -scriptblock $scriptblock -UseWindowsPowerShell

and the c# does the impersonation and runs the PowerShell Scriptblock you gave it (as the user impersonated), so sounds like its what you need?